# Azure Application Gateway redirects http instead of https for backend redirections

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-application-gateway

I have a blazor app that redirects to the login page using 302 redirection. If open it from the local network, it returns in http headers:

```
Status Code: 302
http://myvm/Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2F
```

It works as expected.

When access to this vm from the Azure Application Gateway, the redirection works but the Gateway only replaces the host, not the protocol.

For example, I call:

`https://example.com`

This domain points to the Azure Application Gateway.

The gateway returns

```
Status Code: 302
http://example.com/Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2F
```

Note that it has replaced the host but not the protocol (it should be https, not http).

My workaround is to add a rule for redirection, from https to http.

I do not like it because the gateway still returns http, but then the new rule is executed and redirected to https.

Is there an elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution is to rewrite the `Location` header in your backend responses. [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-portal) describes how you can create a rewrite rule from the Azure portal for specifically the location header. Then create your rule specifically to replace `http://` with `https://`